# Recurring BSOD after new Windows 10 update

Tags: windows-10, bsod

**So windows has done it again.**
I updated my windows around two days ago, and now I suspect it's going to get a blue screen every day at roughly 10 am.

I remember having fixed this problem before, but the solution I used then doesn't apply here, because I don't exactly know the cause of the BSOD this time.

I opened event viewer and all I get is that there was an error, without no clear indication of the culprit.
The event is kernel power 41 (which apparently is caused by a weak energy supply), however, I would be very impressed if I got supply shortage at the very same time two days in a row and then the power ran fine for the rest of the day. It has to be something to do with the update.

I don't know where to begin with this one, Any clues?

Comment: You have told us absolutely nothing about the BSOD. Care to provide some details?

Comment: You did not provide much information, but have you done all driver updates along with Windows Updates?  Have you run Hardware Diagnostics?

Comment: The thing is... I don't know which details I need to provide. Where do I find the information on the bsod? I'm gonna try running hardware diagnostics

Comment: BSOD will create a mini dump file in most cases and will tell you where it put the dump, usually C:\Windows\minidumps.

Comment: You suspect it will BSOD at 10 AM or it does BSOD at 10 AM daily? Have you considered replacing the devices battery.  I assume it’s a laptop

Comment: update: it turns out it was actually a coincide and actual power shortage two days in a row at the same time o.O